# Smooth velocity scroll

Tags: c#, xamarin, skiasharp, skia

I'm trying to implement a smooth slow down scroll based on the velocity of the user gesture.

I'm using `MR.Gestures` to handle the pan gesture and obtain the velocity, then I'm running an animation loop to perform the deceleration but it's very jerky and I'm not sure what I can do to make it smooth.

```
_velocityX = (velocityX / (1000 / SCROLL_INTERVAL));
_velocityY = (velocityY / (1000 / SCROLL_INTERVAL));
```

I have `SCROLL_INTERVAL` set to 16 to scroll at roughly 60fps. My `_friction` variable is currently 0.98f.

In my animation loop I have the following:

```
var distance = new Point
{
    X = 0,
    Y = 0
};

if (Math.Abs(_velocityX) > 0)
{
    distance.X += _velocityX;

    _velocityX *= _friction;
}

if (Math.Abs(_velocityY) > 0)
{
    distance.Y += _velocityY;

    _velocityY *= _friction;
}

<snip>code here moves the camera by the values in distance.X and distance.Y</snip>
```

Now, this works but is very jerky and the issue appears to be that it may be moving by 10+ pixels at the start of the animation.

I believe based on this that my approach is incorrect but I can't find anything to help me change the approach.

Is there a better way to do this? Or a way to make this more smooth?

Comment: to start https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/fling-animation

Comment: and even better https://medium.com/@esskeetit/how-uiscrollview-works-e418adc47060